# How to validate Jinja syntax without variable interpolation

Tags: validation, syntax, jinja2, pre-commit-hook

I have had no success in locating a good precommit hook I can use to validate that a Jinja2 formatted file is well-formed without attempting to substitute variables. The goal is something that will return a shell code of zero if the file is well-formed without regard to whether variable are available, 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this within Jinja itself, you'd just need to write a script to read and parse the template.

Since you **only** care about well-formed templates, and not whether or not the variables are available, it should be fairly easy to do:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# filename: check_my_jinja.py
import sys
from jinja2 import Environment

env = Environment()
with open(sys.argv[1]) as template:
    env.parse(template.read())
```

or something that iterates over all templates

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# filename: check_my_jinja_recursive.py
import sys
import os
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('./mytemplates'))
templates = [x for x in env.list_templates() if x.endswith('.jinja2')]
for template in templates:
    t = env.get_template(template)
    env.parse(t)
```

If you have incorrect syntax, you will get a `TemplateSyntaxError`

So your precommit hook might look like

```
python check_my_jinja.py template.jinja2
python check_my_jinja_recursive.py /dir/templates_folder
```

Comment: The recursive version doesn't quite work because `f` is a list of filenames. Here's one way to run the regular version recursively: `find . -name '*.j2' | xargs -I @ python check_my_jinja.py `